# How to know the full size of memory allocated for a single program in C?

Tags: c, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

To check the program total memory allocated at end of a program, Since i used **free()** function for deallocating an array .

Comment: The standard library provides no standard way for that. What is your real problem? Depending on the system, there are tools (like valgrind) to control the dynamic memory usage.

Comment: You want to know the stack size or the heap size?

Comment: You can use valgrind to get a better idea about memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to know that, and the notion of "full size of memory" is not well defined (and its "allocation" could happen outside and independently of `malloc`, e.g. on Linux by direct calls to [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) etc...)

In practice (assuming your code is running in a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) on some common [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) on a desktop or laptop), think instead in terms of [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

Read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable).

On Linux (but this is Linux specific) you could use `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for details) to query the kernel about the virtual address space and the status of some process. For a process of pid 1234, see `/proc/1234/maps` and `/proc/1234/status` etc.

You could (and probably should) use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to hunt [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

With GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), you also have [mallinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallinfo.3.html) & [malloc_stats(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_stats.3.html) (but they are non-standard) etc...

Be aware that `malloc` and `free` uses lower-level system calls such as [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) & `munmap` (or the older [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html), etc...) to change the virtual address space, but that  `free` usually don't release memory to the kernel with `munmap` but prefers to keep and mark the freed memory zone for future usage by `malloc`.

You could use other [implementations of `malloc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) if you really wanted to (or even provide your own one). But you generally should not.

Comment: I think OP here is concerned about the allocations made by the program and not the actual space utilized by the process. I think he wants a tally of mallocs/frees. Just my interpretation.

Comment: Hence my mention of `valgrind` & `mallinfo` etc